# c++ code-generating rule in cc_library deps?

Tags: bazel

I have automatically-generated `.cc` sources and a Starlark rule running the `.cc` generator:

`BUILD` file:

```
generate_cc(
  name = "foo_generated"
)  # runs an executable that generates foo.h, foo.cc
```

I'd like the above `foo_generated` to act also as a `cc_library`, so that it can be a valid dependency of a subsequent `cc_library`:

```
cc_library(
  name = "bar",
  deps = [":foo_generated"]  # foo_generated used like a cc_library()
)
```

Can `generate_cc` be implemented in a single rule, without macros, so that a target of type `generate_cc` would work as other `cc_library`'s deps?

(I realize that generate_cc could be a macro that calls the actual rule and then calls a `cc_library` rule, thereby creating two separate targets / labels - this is what I'd like to avoid).

---

If a rule implementation could call another rule, then `generate_cc`'s implementation could

1. wrap the sources it generates in a `cc_library`
2. return the `CcInfo` provider returned by `cc_library`

as in (hypothetical `.bzl` file):

```
def generate_cc_impl(ctx):
  # generate .h, .cc files
  # ...
  cc_info = native.cc_library(...)  # wrap .h, .cc files
  return cc_info
```

But I suppose calling one rule from another is not possible?

Answer (score 5):

Rules cannot call other rules. However, support was added fairly recently for rules to reuse most of the native C++ functionality, which supports this use case. There's a section of documentation about [implementing Starlark rules that depend on C++ rules and/or that C++ rules can depend on](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/integrating-with-rules-cc.html#implementing-starlark-rules-that-depend-on-c-rules-andor-that-c-rules-can-depend-on).

The [my_c_archive](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl) example shows a lot of the boilerplate to use this functionality (finding the `cc_toolchain` and `feature_configuration` in particular). [cc_common.compile](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#compile) is the function to create actions to compile your source files. [cc_common.create_linking_context_from_compilation_outputs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_linking_context_from_compilation_outputs) will convert the `CcCompilationOutputs` from `compile` into a `CcLinkingContext` for creating the `CcInfo` to return.

You can choose to pull some/all of the files out of the `CcCompilationOutputs` and `CcLinkingOutputs` to return as your rule's [DefaultInfo](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html), depending on your use case.

`create_linking_context_from_compilation_outputs` returns (`CcLinkingContext`, `CcLinkingOutputs`) for reference. I created [bazel#10253](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/10253) just now to add that to the docs.